# How can I get GrowlTunes to Launch whenever iTunes Launches?

Tags: macos, mac, itunes, xcode, growl

I think I would be able to do this by modifying iTunes' launch services.  Any idea how to go about that?

Would editing its info.plist file in a manner similar to below do what I'm looking for?

`<key>LSOpenApplication</key>`

<string>?</string>

EDIT: Would http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/LSOpenApplication provide any hints?

EDIT2: Last.fm's official Mac Scrobbler (http://www.last.fm/download) is a perfect example of the functionality that I'm looking for.

Comment: Couldn't you just add it to your login items and keep it running all the time?

Comment: @DanielBeck I'm just being anal about RAM used by an application that I never seem to find myself interacting with.  Quicksilver seems to replicate all of its UI functionality in a keyboard-friendly manner.

Comment: @DanielBeck It'd also be nice to have GrowlTunes using precious menu bar space less often.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is create an AppleScript that launches both applications, save that applescript as an application and use that to launch iTunes and GrowlTunes.

In Mac OS X, there is no (easy) functionality that detects application launches.

However, GrowlTunes is designed to be an always open menu extra application, and in fact has a way to launch iTunes from its menu extra. Why not just add it to your login items?

Comment: First approach fails e.g. with media keys launching iTunes, or iTunes start via iTunes Store website redirect.

Comment: I noticed iTunes creates temporary files during launch in ~/Music/iTunes, but they don't exist long enough to trigger a "alert new items" Folder Action, so going that way wouldn't work either.

Comment: I thought of this method before but turned it down for some reason.  Don't remember why; guess I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I guess I could effectively "replace" iTunes in the dock and train Quicksilver and there'd be no difference.

Comment: That's right:  My main gripe against this was that it'd force me to have 2 dock icons for iTunes, but being the keyboard-oriented guy I am I should be satisfied if this is the only solution available.